# How to recursively parse this tree like structure?

Tags: scala, data-structures

Consider a tree-like data structure with the following definition of a node -

```
Node(id:Int, parent: Int, name:Option[String])
```

I have a List[Node] where a Node n with the same parent could have the same id. I want to create a new List[Node] such that each Node has a unique id. It's ok to re-write id and parent of each node to form the output list. I don't need the exact code, just need some hints to go about writing a recursive solution

Example -

Input - `List(Node(5, 0, "a"), Node(2, 5,"b"), Node(2, 5, "c"), Node(3,5, "d"), Node(4, 3,"e"))`

Output - `List(Node(1, 0, "a"), Node(2, 1, "b"), Node(3, 1, "c"), Node(4, 1, "d"), Node(5, 4, "e"))`

Comment: If the input might have duplicate `id` values (`Node(2,5,"b"), Node(2,5,"c")`) , doesn't that mean that a `Node` might have multiple parents (`Node(4,2,"e")`)? How should _that_ translation be handled? Which one is the _real_ parent?

Comment: Is it possible for the input to contain a parent `Node` that comes _after_ the child `Node`? (e.g. `Node(6,9,"f"), Node(9,2,"g")`)

Comment: @jwvh, the input is not expected to have nodes with multiple parents. For the second comment, yes the ordering of nodes in the input list is arbitrary

Answer (score 2):

So we can't renumber any child node until we know the new `id` of the parent node. Not a trivial task.

```scala
case class Node(id:Int, parent: Int, name:String)

def renum(in   :List[Node]
         ,seen :Map[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0)
         ,acc  :List[Node]   = Nil
         ,hold :List[Node]   = Nil) :List[Node] = in match {
  case Nil =>                                            //are we done?
    if (hold.isEmpty) acc.reverse else renum(hold, seen, acc)
  case Node(id,par,nm) :: ns if seen.isDefinedAt(par) => //parent was processed
    val newId = acc.size + 1
    renum(ns, seen+(id->newId), Node(newId,seen(par),nm)::acc, hold)
  case n :: ns =>                                        //put node on hold
    renum(ns, seen, acc, n::hold)
}
```

testing:

```scala
/*
     a 
   / | \
   b c d
       |
       e
*/
val input = List(Node(5,0,"a"),Node(2,5,"b"),Node(2,5,"c"), Node(3,5,"d"),Node(4,3,"e"))

renum(util.Random.shuffle(input))
renum(util.Random.shuffle(input))
renum(util.Random.shuffle(input))
renum(util.Random.shuffle(input))
renum(util.Random.shuffle(input))
//res0: List[Node] = List(Node(1,0,a), Node(2,1,c), Node(3,1,b), Node(4,1,d), Node(5,4,e))
//res1: List[Node] = List(Node(1,0,a), Node(2,1,b), Node(3,1,d), Node(4,1,c), Node(5,3,e))
//res2: List[Node] = List(Node(1,0,a), Node(2,1,b), Node(3,1,d), Node(4,3,e), Node(5,1,c))
//res3: List[Node] = List(Node(1,0,a), Node(2,1,b), Node(3,1,c), Node(4,1,d), Node(5,4,e))
//res4: List[Node] = List(Node(1,0,a), Node(2,1,b), Node(3,1,c), Node(4,1,d), Node(5,4,e))
```